# how do I get IE to support a datepicker in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, datepicker

When I make an input tag for a date in IE using jquery mobile, there isn't a calendar popup that shows like in chrome. Is there a plugin that I could download that would create a calendar popup for IE?

Here is my HTML I'm using:

```
<input id="EndDate" name="EndDate" type="date" value="">
```

And a built-in datepicker isn't available in all versions of IE that I've tested (IE 8, 9, 10, etc.)

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML code to the question. Also please specify the IE version(s) you're testing with.

Comment: Just so you know, the best term to search for HTML5-enabling plugins for IE is "polyfill".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<input type="date">` is not supported as a native feature by any version of IE.

The best solution is to use a "Polyfill" script. Polyfills are small scripts written to add support for a feature that may be missing in certain browsers. Typically they allow the site author to write their normal standard HTML or CSS code, and the polyfill script does the work behind the scenes to make the feature work.

The Modernizr project has [a Wiki page that lists a whole stack of polyfill scripts](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills). This page includes at least two scripts that polyfill the `<input type='date'>` feature. I suggest trying out these scripts first. (there may be others on the web, but if Modernizr are recommending them, then they're probably the best out there)

Talking of [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), you may want to use this script as well, as its job is to help you determine what features the browser supports and thus whether you need to load a polyfill script.

The Modernizr site has good instructions on how to do browser feature detection and how to load polyfill scripts using Modernizr, so I won't repeat it here.

Alternatively if you don't want to use Modernizr, you could write your own feature detection script -- it's pretty easy. Something like this should do the trick:

```
function browserSupportsDateInput() {
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.setAttribute("type", "date");
    return i.type !== "text";
}
```

and then you'd use it like this:

```
if(!browserSupportsDateInput()) {
    //not supported, so run the polyfill script instead.
}
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a 3rd party date picker's for jQuery Mobile.

Only 3 of them are wort mentioning, and every one can be configured to show certain date format and every one of them works on all devices. Thou I would recommend you Mobiscroll because it has skins that looks like native mobile/desktop datepickers.

**[Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/)** - http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/WDjfR/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('#demo').mobiscroll().date({
        invalid: { daysOfWeek: [0, 6], daysOfMonth: ['5/1', '12/24', '12/25'] },
        theme: 'android-ics',
        display: 'inline',
        mode: 'scroller',
        dateOrder: 'dd mm yy',
        dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy"
    });  
});
```

**[Mobipick](http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/)** - http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/zyVjE/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('#demo').mobipick({
        dateFormat: "MM-dd-yyyy"
    });
});
```

**[Datebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/)** - http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ktbcP/

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true, "dateFormat": "mm/dd/YYYY"}'/>
```

Comment: "Only 3 of them are worth mentioning" -- try to keep your answers free of opinion bias. Besides, if this answer is researched a year from now, the options will almost certainly change.

Comment: This is my private objective statement relevant to the group where I am active member, if anyone knows any other solution he is free to write a comment.

Comment: Depending on a developer, be it Mobiscroll or Datebox, ask them on their GitHub page. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bootstrap datepicker to solve this problem in IE.  I am using this datepicker for all browsers with bootstrap 4.3.1 and jquery 3.3.1.

```js
/*call from your document ready code*/
function handleDocumentReady(){
     $('some selector').datepicker({
                       todayBtn: "linked",
                       language: "en",
                       autoclose: true,
                       todayHighlight: true,
                       dateFormat: 'M/d/yyyy'
                   });
}
```

```js
//I use plain old text inputs with custom date validation 
//because I don't like the date validation in some browsers
//,so I copy the values from the text inputs to the date inputs before form submission
//needed to prep date values to be submitted in a form
function beforeSubmit(){
  var isEnglish = "en" == "en";
  var startDate = document.getElementById('startDate');
  var endDate = document.getElementById('endDate');
  if (isEnglish) {
  //ie 6 stuff  (must come before html 5 browser stuff)
     $('#startDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date($('#startDateUI').val()));
     $('#endDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date($('#endDateUI').val()));
  //html 5 compatible browser stuff
     endDate.valueAsDate = new Date($('#endDateUI').val());
     startDate.valueAsDate = new Date($('#startDateUI').val());
  } else {
  //ie 6 stuff (must come before html 5 browser stuff)
     $('#startDate').datepicker("setDate", getCurrentTimezoneDate($('#startDateUI').val()));
     $('#endDate').datepicker("setDate", getCurrentTimezoneDate($('#endDateUI').val()));
  //html5 browser stuff
     var dpg = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal;
     endDate.valueAsDate = dpg.parseDate($('#endDateUI').val(), dpg.parseFormat('dd/mm/yyyy'));
     startDate.valueAsDate = dpg.parseDate($('#startDateUI').val(), dpg.parseFormat('dd/mm/yyyy'));
  }
}
```

```js
                function getCurrentTimezoneDate(target) {
                    var dpg = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal;
                    var d = dpg.parseDate(target, dpg.parseFormat('dd/mm/yyyy'));
                    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset());
                    console.debug(d);
                    return d;
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Now I would use the newer HTML5 `date` inputs by default, they deliver the same native experience on mobile which is superior to any datepicker and has the benefits of consistency across device.

```
<input type="date">
```

As of today only Chrome has support for it on Desktop, it is fair to assume that other browsers will catch up eventually therefore we should develop using this first and use JS to catch the edge cases while we still have to.

I'd use Modernizr to handle these edge cases:

```
if !Modernizr.inputtypes.date
  // initialise your own datepicker 
  // eg. http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js - which has the best support I've seen (IE8+)
```

This way all browsers that can support `date` inputs will, and everything else will initiate a JS datepicker. With the added bonus of 'eventually' factoring out the JS really easily in the future.